# Getting My HTML Form Input to Display

Tags: php, html

I am writing a simple form in my .php document which I have included below. When hitting "Submit", how can I get it to show the entered information on that same page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you want to hold the entered inputs after submission. That would be done with php $_SESSION variables. Here's a good place to start. [http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Comment: Do me a favor and change your form method to "post" instead of "get'Try this in the first name input area: <input type="text" name="firstname" value =<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>/> and let me know if that works then I will give you an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax if you want to display output on same page without refreshing or reloading the page. Easiest method is to use JQuery ajax.

Start by looking at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp if it is new to you.